# Signalr hub does not serialize its method parameter's attributes correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a signalr hub well configured and communicating well with the client.
But my hub method accepts parameters of a specific type, and the class representing this type has Pascal cased properties. As shown below:

```
    public List<DataChanges> Changes { get; set; }
```

But when the client (Javascript client) calls this method, it passes the object correctly but, the Property of this object is always null unless I change the property's name to "CamelCase". As shown below:

```
    public List<DataChanges> changes { get; set; }
```

What I tried:

I added the following attributes each at its own turn to the properties of the object, But the error persisted.

```
    [DataMember(Name = "changes")]
    [JsonProperty("changes")]
```

In my startup class, I added signalr json protocol as follows:

```
 .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(options =>
        {
            //options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new SignalRContractResolver();
            //options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver { NamingStrategy = { OverrideSpecifiedNames = true } };
        })
```

Here is the Signalr contract resolver:

```
public class SignalRContractResolver : IContractResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;
    private readonly IContractResolver _camelCaseContractResolver;
    private readonly IContractResolver _defaultContractSerializer;

    public SignalRContractResolver()
    {
        _defaultContractSerializer = new DefaultContractResolver();
        _camelCaseContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        _assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    }


    public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        if (type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Equals(_assembly))
            return _defaultContractSerializer.ResolveContract(type);

        return _camelCaseContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
    }

}
```

I tried a few other solutions, but nothing worked. The camel case serialization could not be applied by signalr and my property was always null.

Can somebody please tell me a solution for this ?

Comment: What is the .NET Core version of your project? And please share the relevant code of your hub method and js client side.

Comment: I'm running on dotnet core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this  in the startup project:
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options => {options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null
}